# How do I interpret the accuracy of relative importance methods?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, random-forest, regression-coefficients

I'm using [relaimpo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/relaimpo/relaimpo.pdf) package of R for measuring the relative importance of different regressors. It contains several methods such as lmg and pmvd. I wish to evaluate the accuracy of these methods and pick up the most accurate one. Ideally I wish to compare their accuracy with other models such as random forest.